# Flashing of LED

Tags: pi-3, gpio, rpi.gpio, pi-4, led

This is my first post here so HELLO and sorry if I'm posting in the wrong place.
I had assigned a time limit of 40s for led blinking. Can I pause the blinking of this led and make another led to blink for some time and resume the blinking of the led that had been paused earlier?

Comment: Hello @user118263, Welcome and nice to meet you.  Ah, let me see if I understand you requirements correctly. (1) You have two LEDs, let us call them Led1 and Led2, (2) Now you wish to blink the two LEDs in repeated sequence, say, Led1 blinks for 40 seconds, pause and let Led2 blink for 20 seconds, pause and come back to Led1?

Comment: If you want help (other than idle speculation) you need to ask an answerable Question. I guess you have some code, but decline to list it!

Comment: My requirement is that I need to blink the led for 90 seconds. Led1 blinks for 40 seconds and Led2 for 20 seconds, pause and let Led1 to blink for remaining 30 seconds.